# How do I corner bead around two layers of 5/8" drywall?

Tags: drywall, corner-bead

Here it is:

[image]

I still have yet to shave down the rough edges from when I scored and snapped it, but, after that, what can I use for corner bead?

It's entirely possible that I will end up putting up a second layer perpendicular to these two layers so that I will be able to use regular corner bead, but, if I don't need to then I will need to find some way to finish this corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find up to [2 1/2" wide corner bead](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202090330/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&keyword=wide%20corner%20bead&storeId=10051) at [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/). According to my calculations (5/8" + 5/8" + ~1/2" = 1 3/4"), this should be more than wide enough to cover your corners.

The nice thing about paper-faced/backed corner beads, is that you don't have to use nails or screw to install them.  You install them the same way you would tape a normal seam.

- Cut the corner bead to length.
- Apply a layer of mud (joint compound) with a taping knife to the corner (both sides).
- Firmly press the corner bead into the mud.
- Allow mud to dry.

Comment: Mud might be better - I've tried using paper faced corner beads with spray adhesive with poor results.

Comment: So you can just do a good mud job and not even use corner bead?  Thanks for introducing me to the extra large corner bead, Tester.  I should have known to research that.  I'll look more into it and get back to the question later.

Comment: Mud without corner bead can look OK, but will be very easy to chip and damage.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Next time (if there is a next time) maybe stagger the sheets? Then you end up with a regular, 1 sheet corner.

Comment: I only applied a double layer to one side.  The other side of the wall, as of now, still has its original drywall, so staggering won't apply here unless I add another layer to the other wall you see in the pic.  This is what I was referring to when I said "It's entirely possible that I will end up putting up a second layer perpendicular to these two layers so that I will be able to use regular corner bead" in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to cut back your double sheets 1/2" to 3/4", make sure the resulting pocket was relatively square (or rectangular), and then screw a piece (or pieces) of scrap wood (ripped down to the right size) into the gap.  You could drill diagonal pilot holes and get the screws to engage the stud.  Then tape and cornerbead the whole deal.

Answer (score 0):

I am a commercial gc. We use double 5/8 regularly. Forget about the staggered rock and all that. To make it easy on yourself. Leave Home Depot, go to a building supply and ask for oversized metal corner paper faced. It will give you a wider metal face and have paper drywall tape attached to prevent crack throughs. Attach it with spray 90 spray adhesive and then reinforce with staples or screws. Not nails. They will pop and leave you having to constantly repair the corner. Screws you can feel if they catch the stud or not. Happy mudding.